# Can't browse to AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My EC2 instance won't respond when I browse to it using the Public DNS value.

As a test, I tried using curl from within the EC2 instance after ssh into it.  It was successful.  I then tried using curl outside the EC2 instance using the same Public DNS value.  It timed out, as with the browser.

Here are the details.

When I invoke:
'curl http://ec2-54-148-214-212.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' 
from an ssh shell into an Ubuntu EC2 instance, it returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Ubuntu EC2 instance</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

which is expected.  It's the contents of index.html in /var/www/html.

When I invoke that curl command from outside of EC2 instance, it hangs and times out with "Couldn't connect to host".

The Inbound rules for the security group has the http rule enabled:

```
 Type   Protocol  Port Range    Source
 HTTP   TCP       80            0.0.0.0/0
```

Does something else need to be enabled to browse to this EC2 instance?

Comment: The primary difference between accessing ec2-54-148-214-212.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com in these two cases is that outside of your AWS network, that name will resolve to a public IP such as 54.x.y.z but from within your AWS network it will resolve to a private IP such as 10.a.b.c. You can see this if you ping or dig the name from your laptop and then from within your EC2 instance. Your security group rule seems fine, as long as the EC2 instance in question was actually launched with it, but note that it's not relevant to the curl from within the instance itself.

Comment: The main problem I'm having is not being able to browse to my EC2 instance.  I only used curl to demonstrate that browsing to the index file is not possible from outside the EC2 instance.  How can I fix it so I can browse to the html file?

Comment: If you leave the security group wide open (All Traffic), are you able to curl?

Comment: Double-check that the hostname is actually still ec2-54-148-214-212.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.

Comment: @jarmod I just checked, and yes that is still the public dns value.  Just for grins I also used the IP address  with curl http://54.148.214.212

That should also work, but hangs and times out as before.

Comment: @helloV I added a new rule to allow 'All Traffic' and All Protocols and Port Ranges from my ip address.  The curl command still hangs.

Comment: Web server only listening on 127.0.0.1 when it should be on all interfaces (0.0.0.0)? Can you post sanitized output from netstat -anp | grep 80.

Comment: > sudo netstat -anp | grep 80

    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25902/nodejs    
    tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      25299/apache2

Comment: It's common to run node as a non-root user on a high port such as 8080 and then use iptables to redirect port 80 to port 8080, for example "sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080". Are you using iptables?

Comment: No, I haven't set anything with iptables.  Are you suggesting I need to try that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87940/discussion-between-jarmod-and-tgoneil).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the net is that I suggest going back to basics:

- create a security group that allows port 80 and 8080 ingress from 0.0.0.0/0
- launch a new EC2 instance from the stock Amazon Ubuntu AMI, with a public IP, and with the aforementioned security group
- install node.js on the instance
- save the basic node server code below (helloworld.js) on the instance
- run the node server code via *node helloworld.js*
- test that it works on port 8080 via http://hostname:8080
- redirect port 80 to 8080 via *sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080*
- persist this iptables config using [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables)
- remove port 8080 from the security group
- test that it works on port 80 via http://hostname

The skeleton helloworld.js server code is:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text"});
    response.write("Hello world!");
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8080);
console.log("Server is listening on port 8080");
```

Comment: Thank you @jarmod, that works for me.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @tgoneil Glad that it was helpful. Good luck with your project.